# How to factory reset an Arris Surfboard SBG10 modem?

Tags: networking, router, modem

I accidentally locked myself out of my Arris SBG10 modem/wifi router by placing it in bridged mode. No amount of setting my IP address manually and trying to access all of the likely admin interface addresses work (e.g. 192.168.0.1, 192.168.100.1).

The documentation online suggests that holding down the reset button on the back for ~3 seconds will reboot the modem, and 10 seconds will factory reset. However, holding for 10+ seconds doesn't work for me, the modem just reboots without factory resetting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After hours of frustration, I finally solved this. Turns out that on my modem, the reboot and factory reset triggers are SWAPPED compared to the documentation.

With the power on, and the coaxial cable plugged in, my experience is:

1. Press and hold the power button (I used a paperclip)
2. After ~3 seconds, the bottom two icons go dark but the top 3 icons stay green. If I let go of the reset button at this point, the modem is factory reset
3. If I continue to hold, after another ~7 seconds or so all of the lights go dark. If I let go of the reset button at this point, the modem simply reboots but does not reset to factory settings.

Hopefully this helps someone in the future.

I have still not solved my original problem, which was trying to use Google WIFI with this Arris modem. Oh well, I moved the router closer to my desk and that seems to have worked. I did finally get the Aria scale working by switching the 2.4 GHz settings to b/g/n, by default it was g/n.

Comment: Holding 15 seconds worked for me.